# Compilation of std::map::insert_or_assign fails when compiling with Clang on Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, clang++, std

I was trying to compile the code from "The improved interface of the associative containers" from Rainer Grimm's blog but it choked on std::map::insert_or_assign.  Of course on Windows with clang you have to use the GCC headers

The problem is that it comes up with a strange error in the the GCC headers

```
clang++ -O0 -emit-llvm -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 -stdlib=libstdc++ -v -std=c++1z -o preview.bc "..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Libraries\\ModernesCppSource\\source\\preview.cpp" 
clang version 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_400/final)
Target: i686-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: E:\Compilers\LLVM32\bin
 "E:\\Compilers\\LLVM32\\bin\\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple i686-w64-windows-gnu -emit-llvm-bc -emit-llvm-uselists -disable-free -main-file-name preview.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -v -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -coverage-notes-file "E:\\Documents\\Programming\\Code\\Local Projects\\CEvelop\\AnotherSolutionIMeanWorkspace\\Test2\\Debug\\preview.gcno" -resource-dir "E:\\Compilers\\LLVM32\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\4.0.0" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\i686-w64-mingw32" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\backward" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\7.1.0" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\7.1.0\\i686-w64-mingw32" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\7.1.0\\backward" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\include\\c++\\7.1.0" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\include\\c++\\7.1.0\\i686-w64-mingw32" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\include\\c++\\7.1.0\\backward" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\7.1.0\\include\\c++" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\7.1.0\\include\\c++\\i686-w64-mingw32" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\7.1.0\\include\\c++\\backward" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\LLVM32\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\4.0.0\\include" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\7.1.0\\include" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\7.1.0\\include-fixed" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include" -internal-isystem "E:\\Compilers\\mingw32\\include" -O0 -Wall -std=c++1y -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir "E:\\Documents\\Programming\\Code\\Local Projects\\CEvelop\\AnotherSolutionIMeanWorkspace\\Test2\\Debug" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -o preview.bc -x c++ "..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Libraries\\ModernesCppSource\\source\\preview.cpp"
clang -cc1 version 4.0.0 based upon LLVM 4.0.0 default target i686-pc-windows-msvc
ignoring nonexistent directory "E:\Compilers\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "E:\Compilers\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\i686-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "E:\Compilers\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "E:\Compilers\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\7.1.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "E:\Compilers\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\7.1.0\i686-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "E:\Compilers\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\7.1.0\backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "E:\Compilers\mingw32\include\c++\7.1.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "E:\Compilers\mingw32\include\c++\7.1.0\i686-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "E:\Compilers\mingw32\include\c++\7.1.0\backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "E:\Compilers\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 E:\Compilers\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\7.1.0\include\c++
 E:\Compilers\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\7.1.0\include\c++\i686-w64-mingw32
 E:\Compilers\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\7.1.0\include\c++\backward
 E:\Compilers\LLVM32\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include
 E:\Compilers\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\7.1.0\include
 E:\Compilers\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\7.1.0\include-fixed
 E:\Compilers\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include
 E:\Compilers\mingw32\include
End of search list.
E:\Compilers\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\7.1.0\include\c++\optional:1032:27: error: use of class template 'optional' requires template arguments
  template <typename _Tp> optional(_Tp) -> optional<_Tp>;
                      ^
E:\Compilers\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\7.1.0\include\c++\optional:451:11: note: template is declared here
class optional
      ^
E:\Compilers\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\7.1.0\include\c++\optional:1032:40: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
  template <typename _Tp> optional(_Tp) -> optional<_Tp>;
                                   ^
E:\Compilers\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\7.1.0\include\c++\optional:1032:41: error: cannot use arrow operator on a type
  template <typename _Tp> optional(_Tp) -> optional<_Tp>;
                                        ^
```

3 errors generated.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Hint: You have tagged the question `c++1z` but use the option `-std=c++1y` when compiling. `C++1y` was the code-name for the C++14 standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, well spotted I have updated the question with the new error

Comment: And clang on windows uses headers from mingw?

Comment: Just for the standard library, libc++ is not a yet ready for Windows, so you have to use libstdc++ from GNU